# Шрифт висит в системе , не могу найти, что бы удалить

Tags: windows, windows-10, шрифты

Всем привет ! 
Вопрос возможно дилетанский, но уже не знаю куда копать.
Есть сайт, только на нем проблема. При открытии страницы отображается неверный шрифт Ubuntu . По инспектору, он задан первым, но отрабатывать должен Helvetica, который второй в списке. 
Хочу найти шрифт Ubuntu и удалить его. 
В папке со шрифтами его нет, в regedit в папке Fonts его нет, он есть только в Параметрах системы -> Парамерты шрифта.
Как его найти и удалить, кто подскажет ? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Тот редкий случай, когда скриншот бы не помешал. Не имею понятия, где вот это `Параметры системы -> Параметры шрифта` на английском интерфейсе...

Comment: Пардоньте. Вот единственное место, где я его нашел http://joxi.ru/Q2KeVMEfLXR4Vr

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что шрифта нет в `C:/Windows/Fonts`? Вы включили отображение скрытых файлов перед проверкой? Могу посоветовать метод "клин клином вышибают". Скачайте набор Ubuntu шрифтов [здесь](https://design.ubuntu.com/font/) - линка на .zip в самом низу страницы, распакуйте и установите шрифт Ubuntu. А потом снесите его и посмотрите что получилось. Также у меня есть смутное подозрение, что этот шрифт может быть связан с WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), которая тоже на Ubuntu...

Comment: Спасибо за совет , суйчас будем посмотреть